# Is it possible to inject a react component from Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I know that with React, you can target specific elements based on their id's and render a specific component within them like this:

```
if(document.getElementById('root')) {
    const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
    root.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
            <SomeComponent/>
        </React.StrictMode>
    );
}
```

Then, by bundling the build scripts you can link them in any external webpage and have a dive with an id of root to render that component.

Can this be done with Next.js somehow? I've attempted to use the export functionality and use the chunks that are built, but I'm having trouble finding a way to render any component in a div. Thanks in advance for any help with this!

I've tried the react solution, but wasn't able to accomplish this.

TLDR: I want to have a simple test.html webpage that is separate from the Next.js application. Then I want to import the Next.js exported bundle links (js files) to this text.html page. Within test.html, I would have the following div:
`<div id="root"> </div>`
My goal is to have the bundled js be able to inject a component from the Next.js application into this external text.html webpage.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can achive this with [next dynamic import](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import)

example:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
    
const Component = dynamic(() =>
  import("../components/component").then(module =>
    module), { ssr: false });

export default function Home() {
  return <Component />
}
```

if you need to get a DOM elemnt with nextjs, you can access the DOM inside a `useEffect` with no dependencies (it runs in the client)

Comment: So would this be the code within the external website, or this is a component I would write in my Next.js website? My use case would be to use a simple html webpage, import the bundles and then just have a div with an id of root and that's all. The bundled imports would then need to inject the component in the div with the id of root.

Comment: I added a TLDR snippet to my original question to hopefully explain it a bit more simply of what I want to achieve.